# How much XP exactly is earned per Enchanting action?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to level Enchanting efficiently, but I cannot find how much XP is earned per action, such as via disenchantment, enchantment, or recharging. What determines how much XP is earned per action?

Answer (score 2):

You should enchant items with whatever petty gems/small souls you have because `Crafting enchanted items gives the biggest overall skill increases` - [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting#Gaining_Skill_XP) and `Experience is the same regardless of what is enchanted.` - [the other wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_%28Skyrim%29#Leveling).

If you do happen to have the [Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star_%28item%29) you might have more fun slaying and constantly recharging your weapons but `Recharging enchanted weapons using Soul Gems gives small to moderate skill increases, based on the size of the soul used`.

Creating enchanted weapons will also leave you with ludicrous amounts of valuables at the end, but it can be difficult getting so many souls/gems/items without going out and killing things anyway.
I can only give you relative notions of experience gained per method as that's all I can find.

Comment: I'm obsessive about getting as many souls through my Black Star as I can: I'm about level 76 in Enchanting, only ever having enchanted one set of gear. And I'm in the level 30s, late.